# If i give overflow:hidden to my popover , arrow is getting hidden. How to avoid this?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I have given a link for it
https://jsfiddle.net/Sydney_o9/66uqd12s/7/

```
#my-popover {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

I need to give overflow:hidden to wrap the contents inside my popover.So how can i wrap the contents in popover without making arrow hidden.

If anyone knows please do help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden` to the CSS class `.popover-content` instead, as follows:

```css
.popover-content {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

This way the arrow will not be influenced, just the text inside the popover body.

[image: dev tools view of popover code]

Updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/66uqd12s/174/